# Are SMTP headers retained when an email is forwarded or replied to?

Tags: smtp, forwarding, mail-forwarding, email

Let's say an email is sent from party A to B.  Let's refer to the set of headers that B views as Headers 1.  Party B then replies to or forwards the email to party C.  Let's refer to the set of headers that C views as Headers 2.  Does any information from Headers 1 persist separate from or as a part of Headers 2?

Comment: Downvoted because asked elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. SMTP Has no concept of forwarding. You basically send a new email. And that is technically correct - after all, you send the new text to your email server.

Comment: this seems to conflict with the answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/163160/when-an-email-is-forwarded-does-it-lose-its-original-headers which indicates the answer is implementation-specific... ?

Comment: No. Read that again. The CLIENT (MUA) ma decide to include the old headers in the new email. But that is not part of the SMTP protocol. A SMTP Server wont delete them. If that happens, it is totally a client functionality.